# Mysql two queries in one (inner join?)

Tags: mysql

I need to return the results of two queries within one. I've read other posts and am not sure if this should be an inner join.

I would like these two queries:

```
MariaDB [servers]> select * from servers;
+----+------------+---------+------------+
| id | servername | ip      | returncode |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | server1    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          |
|  2 | server2    | 0.0.0.0 | 1          |
|  3 | server2    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          |
|  4 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          |
|  5 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          |
|  6 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          |
|  7 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          |
+----+------------+---------+------------+

MariaDB [servers]> select servername,count(returncode) from servers where returncode<>0 group by servername;
+------------+-------------------+
| servername | count(returncode) |
+------------+-------------------+
| server2    |                 1 |
| server3    |                 3 |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Into something like this:

```
MariaDB [servers]> select ?????????
+----+------------+---------+------------+-------------------+
| id | servername | ip      | returncode | count(returncode) |
+----+------------+---------+------------+-------------------+
|  1 | server1    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          | 0                 |
|  2 | server2    | 0.0.0.0 | 1          | 1                 |
|  3 | server2    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          | 1                 |
|  4 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 0          | 3                 |
|  5 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          | 3                 |
|  6 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          | 3                 |
|  7 | server3    | 0.0.0.0 | 4          | 3                 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+-------------------+
```

Can someone please help me understand how to do this? I feel like this is an inner join, however I'm not sure I understand this concept completely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the count of the `returncode` for each server, then use an `LEFT JOIN` to your `servers` table to get the result:

```
select s.id, s.servername, s.ip, s.returncode, 
  coalesce(c.totalcount, 0) TotalCount
from servers s
left join
(
  select servername, count(returncode) TotalCount
  from servers
  where returncode<>0
  group by servername
) c
  on s.servername = c.servername;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36b0b/8)

I chose a `LEFT JOIN` so you will return all rows from the `servers` table even if there is not a matching row in the subquery.